# How do I set Heroku as git's origin?

Tags: git, heroku

Currently I have to submit stuff via: git push heroku master

Heroku is not the origin for some reason, github is - I don't want it to be though - I think it's because I downloaded the GitHub desktop client anyways.

Anyways - how do I make heroku the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`git remote set-url origin git@heroku.com:<repo>.git`

Answer (score 1):

You can rename a remote with

```
git remote rename heroku origin
```

Comment: I got an error with this - but the person's code below works.